# VS2010 Umbraco Project Template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, project, umbraco

Getting Umbraco up and running today hasn't been much easier than last time 2 or 3 years ago (took 8 attempts!). However, In VS2010 used the Extension Manager to add the Umbraco Project template.  It installed ok but I can't find it anywhere when I want to create a new Project. Where should I see it and under what conditions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Platform Installer?  That's the easiest way to get Umbraco installed IMO.

Comment: Yes, I installed it with the platform installer but that doesn't install the Umbraco Project Template in VS2010 AND tell you how to use it.  My issue is, it's installed, but I don't see it in any of the project dialogues to be able to use it.